# ZeroMQ Subscriber stops receiving messages after a while

Tags: php, zeromq

I run a ZeroMQ subscriber demon. It works for a while but the subscribing stops at some point, e.g. 1 month later, even the subscribing process is alive.
I have experienced this issue several times and I didn't notice until someone said.
I need to detect this issue. Do you have any good idea to detect this issue?

Once I detect this issue, I always restart the subscriber script. It will work after that. Thus, regular restarting process would be one possible way. But I think there is more smart way.

I'm using libzmq, php-zmq and PHP5. libzmq is version 4.2.1.

```
<?php
if (class_exists("ZMQ") && defined("ZMQ::LIBZMQ_VER")) {
    echo ZMQ::LIBZMQ_VER, PHP_EOL; // 4.2.1
}
```

The following is my PHP subscribe script. Normally it works. But it will not print out after working for a long time.

```
$subscriber = new \ZMQSocket(new \ZMQContext(), \ZMQ::SOCKET_SUB);
$subscriber->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:9999");
$subscriber->setSockOpt(\ZMQ::SOCKOPT_SUBSCRIBE, "type");

while (true) {
    $messages = $subscriber->recvMulti();
    $topic = $messages[0];
    print $topic;
}
```

---

Update 1

I found this PDF. (memo for me)

http://zguide2.wdfiles.com/local--files/page:start/zguide-php.pdf

---

Update 2

2 or 3 messages are published for a second. I think it is quite often. The data is bitcoin transaction data which came from zeromq of bitcoin core.

bitcoin core has zeromq publish feature.

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/master/src/zmq

Comment: How often are messages published?  If they are infrequent it's possible the connection is timing out.

Comment: Hi. Quite often. 2 or 3 messages for a second. The data is bitcoin transaction data which came from zeromq of bitcoin core.